# Document properties in Word and PDF files

Tags: c#, pdf, document, docx, gembox-document

I'm trying to read a specific property from a Word file with [GemBox.Document](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document), but in some cases, it might not be in the document, so I get an error.

```
var document = DocumentModel.Load("ovl-last.docx");
var documentProperties = document.DocumentProperties;
var ovldoctype = documentProperties.Custom["DocType"];
```

In the [Document Properties](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/examples/word-properties/211) example, I noticed that we can iterate through the properties. Is this the only "safe" way to get a property and prevent an exception, or is there another way to check its existence?

Also, when I save the `DocumentModel` to PDF I noticed that I get a hard-coded "GemBox.Document XYZ" value for the "PDF Producer" property. I can see it in: Adobe Reader -> File -> Properties... -> Advanced -> PDF Producer

Can I change this to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that both [`DocumentProperties.BuiltIn`](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/docs/GemBox.Document.BuiltInDocumentPropertiesDictionary.html) and [`DocumentProperties.Custom`](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/docs/GemBox.Document.CustomDocumentPropertiesDictionary.html) are dictionaries, so you can either use `TryGetValue` to try retrieving the "DocType" value or use `ContainsKey` method to check if the "DocType" key exists.

For instance, something like this:

```
var document = DocumentModel.Load("ovl-last.docx");
var documentProperties = document.DocumentProperties;
if (document.DocumentProperties.Custom.TryGetValue("DocType", out object ovldoctype))
{
    // ...
}
```

Or this:

```
var document = DocumentModel.Load("ovl-last.docx");
var documentProperties = document.DocumentProperties;
if (document.DocumentProperties.Custom.ContainsKey("DocType"))
{
    var ovldoctype = documentProperties.Custom["DocType"];
    // ...
}
```

Regarding the "PDF Producer", try adding the "Producer" property:

```
documentProperties.Custom.Add("Producer", "My value for PDF Producer");
document.Save("ovl-last.pdf");
```